# Making hats (and other accents) bold

Tags: math-mode, bold, accents

I've been typesetting some equations, and I've found that the default behavior accents like `\hat`, `\bar`, `\tilde`, etc. makes a rather small and easily-missed mark. Is there some way to make the accents stand out more? In particular, is there any way to make them appear in bold (without affecting the letter they are over)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is one solution, albeit cumbersome:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\thickhat}[1]{\mathbf{\hat{\text{$#1$}}}}
\newcommand{\thickbar}[1]{\mathbf{\bar{\text{$#1$}}}}
\newcommand{\thicktilde}[1]{\mathbf{\tilde{\text{$#1$}}}}
\begin{document}
$\hat{a}, \bar{a}, \tilde{a}$ \par
$\hat{\mathbf{a}}, \bar{\mathbf{a}}, \tilde{\mathbf{a}}$ \par
$\mathbf{\hat{a}}, \mathbf{\bar{a}}, \mathbf{\tilde{a}}$ \par
$\thickhat{a}, \thickbar{a}, \thicktilde{a}$ \par
\end{document}
```

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides the easy font-and-size switching capability via `\text`. This allows you to use the `\thick`-constructs inside super-/subscripts.

Comment: @yrudoy and Werner: This solution doesn't properly place the bold accent. For example, `\thickhat{A}` doesn't yield the desired output.

Answer (score 20):

`bm` package can help here.

[image]

The first row is normal, the second is normal with bold accents and the third is all bold.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\showoutput

$\hat{a }\bar{a} \tilde{a}$

$\bm\hat{a} \bm\bar{a} \bm\tilde{a}$


$\bm{\hat{a}} \bm{\bar{a}} \bm{\tilde{a}}$


\end{document}
```

Comment: How to define a new command which can do that ?. I tried  \renewcommand\bar{\bm\bar}, but it does not work.

Comment: @LlavDem that defines `\bar` to be an infinite loop. just use `\newcommand\boldbar{\bm\bar}` (or use `\bmdefine`)

Comment: Using `\bm\bar{\mathbb{R}}` does not seem to work (with, say, `amsfonts` loaded so as to produce the blackboard bold letter).

Comment: @murray I just added `$\bm\hat{\mathbb{R}}$` to the above and changed the preamble to  `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}` and it worked fro me

Comment: @David Carlisle: You're correct. Not sure what I did that originally didn't make it work for me.